# drawing a AST tree with antlr and c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, antlr, parse-tree

i'm studying how it works ANTLR, in this guide
https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Getting+Started+with+ANTLR+v4

at the end it create a parse tree like this 
[image]

(don't matter the tag, the grammar is in italian)
anyway is there a method in c# with ANTLR4 that could draw a tree like that?
i really need it

Thank you all!

Comment: You could output a file in .dot notation and use Graphviz (http://www.graphviz.org/)  to render it...

Comment: yes but i thought like in java there was a method in c#